# Error: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() In Flutter and Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, web

am building a Flutter application and I have integrated Firebase (for android and web), but I keep getting this error when I click on a button either to register, login, or logout. I have seen other people have asked the same question, but none of the solutions seems to work for me. I am using Flutter and Android Studio. How can I fix this problem?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: "webapp-conn",
      apiKey: apiKey,
      appId: appId,
      messagingSenderId:
      messagingSenderId,
      projectId: projectId)
  ),
  );

  runApp(
  MultiProvider(
  providers: [
  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AuthService()),
  ],
  child: MyApp(),`your text`
  ),
  );
  }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // Adicione esta linha para criar uma instância do FirebaseApp
  final FirebaseApp app = Firebase.app("webapp-conn");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: AppColors.mainOrangeColor,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          child: LoginScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

******* Terminal details *************

Error: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49 throw* packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 329:9 app packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 56:41 app packages/firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart 44:47 get instance packages/webapp/services/auth_service.dart 10:37 new packages/webapp/main.dart 28:53 <fn> packages/provider/src/inherited_provider.dart 736:29 get value packages/provider/src/inherited_provider.dart 590:33 get value packages/provider/src/provider.dart 303:37 of packages/provider/src/provider.dart 649:21 ReadContext.read packages/webapp/login_screen.dart 65:41 login dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54 runBody dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5 _async packages/webapp/login_screen.dart 63:8 login packages/webapp/login_screen.dart 360:41 <fn> packages/flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 1154:21 handleTap packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 275:24 invokeCallback packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 654:11 handleTapUp packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 311:5 [_checkUp] packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 244:7 handlePrimaryPointer packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 630:9 handleEvent packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 98:12 [_dispatch] packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 143:9 <fn> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:13 forEach packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 141:17 [_dispatchEventToRoutes] packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 127:7 route packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 465:19 handleEvent packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 445:14 dispatchEvent packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 331:11 dispatchEvent packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 400:7 [_handlePointerEventImmediately] packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 363:5 handlePointerEvent packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 320:7 [_flushPointerEventQueue] packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 293:9 [_handlePointerDataPacket] lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1251:13 invoke1 lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 269:5 invokeOnPointerDataPacket lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 168:39 [_onPointerData] lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 791:20 <fn> lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 720:14 <fn> lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 317:16 loggedHandler dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 367:37 _checkAndCall dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 372:39 dcall

I tried youtube and stackoverflow solutions but none of them seems to work for me.